# How could I send the windows eventlog to the network logging of a linux server?

Tags: windows-event-log, syslog-ng

In Windows, I am using the "Eventlog to Syslog" utility to send event logs to the Linux syslog server (syslog-ng). But I am can't do the same with some log files, especially in the case of the IIS log.

Why is it impossible with the named tool?

How could I send these log files to the syslog server using the eventlog to syslog utility?

Comment: I tried to fix your question, because it was interesting, but I won't be any time with you.

Comment: Doing so makes windows eventlog not consumable in a standard way, what is not desirable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use nxlog for this, which ends up sending Windows event logs, IIS logs, Exchange logs, and more to (in my case) a central nxlog server where it gets written to files and send to an ELK stack. Its free, native and multiplatform, so we use it on Windows and Linux. It can send over TLS too, and can send using JSON if you want.

http://nxlog-ce.sourceforge.net/

Comment: the Linux Syslog server I am using is Syslog-ng, so would it be better to use the same syslog server windows agent,in this case, windows syslog-ng agent

Comment: No, as you will lose a lot of information. You can gain a lot by exporting logs uniformly as JSON.

Comment: Is it possible to use nxlog in windows and forward the logs to linux syslog-ng server, as in my case its difficult to change the syslog-ng servers in linux.

Comment: Yes, you can. But what then? You may find that there is a pile of poorly structured log data. You may like to convert the format first to something that can be usefully flattened, such as JSON

Comment: New to this logging environment and tools, hence lots of doubt. To be clear 1) In the input module of nxlog format/parse the logs to JSON. 2) In output module provide the syslog-ng server info 3) In Route forward the input to output. Correct me if I'm wrong Cameron

Comment: In input you read from the windows event log and do any parsing (adding fields etc). I suggest you do your conversion to JSON in your output, then to syslog.

Comment: Took a while for me to configure and check. It was working fine the logs were forwarded to the syslog server in the required format. Appreciate the guidance provided Cameron Kerr

Comment: You should put a filter in place to configure which messages you want sent. Will be rather high volume otherwise.

Comment: Using nxlog 'im_mseventlog' module I'm able to forward all Windows Logs (Application, Security, System... ) logs to the remote syslog server. But I'm not able to forward eventlogs present under 'Application and Service Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security Logs' to the syslog server using nxlog. Is there any module to forward those event logs